# Is there a way to autopopulate words for columns,tables, etc. in pgAdmin?

Tags: pgadmin

On the query editor, is there a way to autopopulate words for columns,tables, etc. in pgAdmin?

Comment: You are right! the SQL client I am using i pg4admin

Comment: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/query_tool.html#the-sql-editor-panel